# How To Upgrade Kubuntu From 16.04 to 16.10 using Kubuntu 16.10 ISO Image File?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kubuntu, iso, 16.10

I have just downloaded the latest image ISO file of Kubuntu 16.10.

I would like to learn if there is a way to upgrade my current operating system from Kubuntu 16.04 LTS to Kubuntu 16.10 using the new ISO image file that I have just downloaded.

**Note:**
I know that I can get the latest upgrade using the following command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

The above upgrade command though will re-download the same files that I have already downloaded.

Comment: No, the commands you posted only update within the same release (and `time sudo`... is a mistake anyway). There's a way to do it with a command but that besides the point since you want to do it with the ISO you already have an for that you just need to boot from it and follow instructions. At one point you'll be asked whether to erase and install 16.10, install side by side or upgrade.

Comment: @CelticWarrior : Thank you for pointing out the mistake in the command. I have fixed it already although it is beyond the objective of the question.